# Publish using Ivy without Ant

Tags: java, publish, ivy

I have a custom package and custom installer tool. That tool uses Ivy internally for dependency management and upload to Nexus. The problem is that I am unable to publish and tutorials are only in connection with Ant. How to publish using Ivy alone?

I have three files in my working folder

- package-bundle.zip
- ivy.xml
- ivysettings.xml

Then I run 
`$ java -jar ivy.jar -settings ivysettings.xml -publish nexus -publishpattern "[artifact]-[type].[ext]" -makepom pom.xml`

### ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.company" module="package" revision="1.0"/>
    <publications>
        <artifact ext="zip" type="bundle"/>
    </publications>
</ivy-module>
```

### ivysettings.xml

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="workbench"/>
    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="nexus" m2compatible="true" usepoms="true" root="https://mycompany.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots"/>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

The `publish` step never kicks in.

### Output

```
:: loading settings :: file = ivysettings.xml
:: resolving dependencies :: com.company#package;1.0
        confs: [default]
:: resolution report :: resolve 34ms :: artifacts dl 0ms
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
        |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |      default     |   0   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   0   |   0   |
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why it never even try to publish?

Comment: Ivy was designed and developed to help the developers who have been working in Apache Ant. Ivy works only with Ant.

Comment: I was missing only `-revision "X.Y"` for Ivy to publish. So in general, it is necessary to specify all options under the `publish options`